# input file - change text button of data-button-text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm using this angular file upload ([nervgh/angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)) in my angular app. It works very well and I have no problems with the uploads.

I have one problem with one button, this is the button exaple code:

```
<input filestyle="" type="file" data-button-text="Single" 
       data-class-button="btn btn-default" data-classinput="form-control inline" 
       nv-file-select="" uploader="form.uploader" class="form-control"/>
```

I would like to set `data-button-text` with one variable since my app has 3 different languages.

Something like this: `data-button-text="form.variable-text"` (or some kind of variable) instead a string like `data-button-text="Single"`

At the moment, I'm not able to change that text by any variable. I tried a lot of times with differents ways without any success. I can't use angular curly braces or controller variables. At least, I dont know how to do it.

Any help? Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `data-button-text="{{variable}}"`?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Goldenowner Yes, I did. I tried a lot of before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Jorge.

I think the property you are searching is "data-buttontext" instead of "data-button-text".

Tell me on friday at the office meeting if it worked.